# Error after uninstalling a Tomcat server and JDK in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Below is the error that I keep getting after I have uninstalled my JDK and server under Eclipse. I have installed them back but my code keeps getting an error:

```
Mar 19, 2019 3:59:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_201/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_201/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_201/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Users\userpc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\athirah\eclipse;;.
Mar 19, 2019 3:59:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:kolej' did not find a matching property.
Mar 19, 2019 3:59:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Comment: Please include the server settings under eclipse

Comment: @RannLifshitz what do u mean?? files under server folder?? web-xml ?